# ViewPager не корректно работает

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Ситуация такая - есть фрагмент `fragmentBoss`, в нем  `ViewPager` с 3 страницами (фрагментами). захожу в фрагмент `fragmentBoss` - и `ViewPager` отображает фрагменты как надо, затем выхожу и захожу на другой фрагмент (`Settings`), и захожу опять в фрагмент `fragmentBoss` с `ViewPager` и страницы пустые, обновляются только после перелистывания.

```
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentBoss= new FragmentBoss();
    fragmentPoiskaIStarta = new FragmentPoiskaIStarta();
    fragmentSettings = new FragmentSettings();
}
```

Тут метод, посредством которого переходим по фрагментам (`fragmentBoss`, `Settings`):

```
transaction1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
switch (TipAnimacii) {

    case 1: {
        transaction1.replace(R.id.BigFragment, fragmentPoiskaIStarta);
        transaction1.commit();


        mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.prozrahnost);
        mTextMessage.startAnimation(anim);

        break;
    }
    case 2: {
                 transaction1.replace(R.id.BigFragment, fragmentBoss);
                 transaction1.commit();

        mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.prozrahnost);
        mTextMessage.startAnimation(anim);

        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        transaction1.replace(R.id.BigFragment, fragmentSettings);
        transaction1.commit();

        mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.prozrahnost);
        mTextMessage.startAnimation(anim);

        break;
    }
}
```

Класс FragmentBoss:

```
public class FragmentBoss extends Fragment {

    public static FragmentBoss newInstance() {
        FragmentBoss fragment = new FragmentBoss();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_boss, container, false);
         viewPager =(ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);


        TablayautAdapter tablayautAdapterv=new TablayautAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tablayautAdapterv);


        tabLayout=(TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return v;
    }
```

Класс TablayautAdapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.kaz.io.Fragment.FragmentControl;
import com.example.kaz.io.Fragment.FragmentControlCsene;

public class TablayautAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private String[] tabs;

    public TablayautAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs=new String[]{
                "TAB1",
                "TAB2",
                "TAB3",
                "TAB4"  };
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

               return FragmentControl.newInstance();
            case 1:

                return FragmentControlCsene.newInstance();
            case 2:

                return FragmentControlCsene.newInstance();
            case 3:

                return FragmentControl.newInstance();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }
}
```

---

Я от части понял свою проблему. Я сделал так, как мне посоветовал сделать Andriy Martsinkevych, за что ему огромное спасибо). Но если зайти в фрагмент `FragmentBoss`, потом перейти на другой фрагмент, а потом заново зайти на `FragmentBoss` вылетает ошибка, которая приводиться в сообщении ниже. Данная проблема решается если `TablayautAdapter` наследовать не от `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, а от `FragmentPagerAdapter` и ошибка уходит и все работает как надо. Однако минус этого всего в том что, данные в фрагментах которые находятся в `ViewPager` обнуляются. Если кто знает более лучший способ пишите )

---

Захожу в фрагмент `fragmentBoss` - и `ViewPager` отображает фрагменты как надо, затем захожу на другой фрагмент (`Settings`), и захожу опять в фрагмент `fragmentBoss` с `ViewPager` и вылетает ошибка.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:898)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:215)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1452)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12012)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2645)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11990)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:483)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1358)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
TablayautAdapter tablayautAdapterv = new TablayautAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Вылетает с ошибкой

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё одно решение, чтобы избежать ошибки. Делаем так, как посоветовал Andriy Martsinkevych и в классе `TablayautAdapter` добавляем этот код:

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    try{
        super.restoreState(state, loader);
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        // null caught
    }
}
```

При этом, `TablayautAdapter` можно наследовать от `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.